# Android video downloading in full hd quality

Tags: android

I want to download videos from youtube from android phone. I have a Samsun Galaxy S 5 so i want to be fullhd videos. How can i make it? I have android version 4.4 and I tried a lot of programs but none of them worked. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be on [android stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) Since it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit illegal so don't post more questions like this one please. But you can try tubemate: http://m.tubemate.net/